# RestKit installation error with Xcode 4.4 and iOS 5

Tags: xcode, restkit

I am having some issues in including RestKit in my project. It is something which I have done previously in Lion several times and haven't had any issues.

I am now trying it for an iOS app on Mountain Lion, with Xcode 4.4 and iOS Deployment Target iOS 5.

1. While trying to import RestKit from github, after the import completes surprisingly a folder called RestKit is created at target location, there are no files in it!
2. So I then just downloaded, RestKit from the site and dragged and dropped the folder into a new project and followed all the steps required for linking, etc.

However, on importing RestKit.h, it says 'file not found' and a build also shows several 'format string' and semantic (isa deprecated) issues.

Could anyone advise on this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just seems to be something that is for the moment broken in the master branch. Used the development branch instead of master branch and these issues did not occur.

(git submodule add -b development git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git)